# Recover from "FAULTED" zfs pool. "-F" option seems to be ignored

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, corruption, zpool

On Ubuntu, I recently started trying out ZFS on an external USB hard drive.  I now seem to have a corrupted zfs pool, which probably happened simply as a result of me shutting down my computer (with `poweroff`).

```
$ zpool import
   pool: zfs
     id: 1234512345123451234
  state: FAULTED
 status: The pool metadata is corrupted.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
    The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
    the '-f' flag.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-72
 config:

        zfs                      FAULTED  corrupted data
          usb-Disk_Name_etc-0:0  ONLINE
```

When trying to import it I get this helpful message explaining that I'll lose about 1 second of data (which would be fine) and that I can attempt recovery with the "-F" option:

```
$ zpool import zfs
cannot import 'zfs': I/O error
    Recovery is possible, but will result in some data loss.
    Returning the pool to its state as of Thu 12 Mar 2020 00:58:03 GMT
    should correct the problem.  Approximately 1 seconds of data
    must be discarded, irreversibly.  Recovery can be attempted
    by executing 'zpool import -F zfs'.  A scrub of the pool
    is strongly recommended after recovery.
```

Using the dry-run flag, I get confirmation that -F should work:

```
$ zpool import -Fn zfs
Would be able to return zfs to its state as of Thu 12 Mar 2020 00:58:03 GMT.
Would discard approximately 1 seconds of transactions.
```

But, when I try the real thing, it seems to completely ignore the "-F" option and repeats the original message:

```
$ zpool import -F zfs
cannot import 'zfs': I/O error
    Recovery is possible, but will result in some data loss.
    Returning the pool to its state as of Thu 12 Mar 2020 00:58:03 GMT
    should correct the problem.  Approximately 1 seconds of data
    must be discarded, irreversibly.  Recovery can be attempted
    by executing 'zpool import -F zfs'.  A scrub of the pool
    is strongly recommended after recovery.
```

I found mention of the "-X" option from this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/645866/74394 but I continue to get exactly the same message.  I've tried all of these option combinations, both with the pool name (zfs) and the numerical ID number (like 1234512345123451234), and I always get exactly the same message as above suggesting to use the -F option.

`-F`
`-FX`
`-f`
`-fF`
`-fFX`

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?  ZFS seems incredibly flaky if I've irretrievably lost the whole disk just because of 1 second of data due to a system shutdown!  I don't have a backup copy of the pool since I'd only just started trying out ZFS.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that USB device is lying about commits, all bets are off because the writes could be re-ordered, and between write re-ordering and lying about barriers, all bets are off on whether the metadata is trashed.

Try:
zdb -e zfs -ul

This will hopefully list some txgs.

Then try:
zpool import -f -FX -N -T [txg_number]

where you got the txg_number from zdb above.

Other things to try:
Update ZFS to latest 0.8.3. What ships with Ubuntu is quite ancient and there have been a lot of fixes and improvements since that version.

Comment: Thanks for this.  `zdb -e zfs -ul` gives me 32 Uberblocks under "LABEL 0" and another one under "LABEL 2", although the txg of the latter matches with one of the txg's in the former list.  I tried doing `zpool import -f -FX -N -T <txg>` for every single txg listed, but sadly it gives me this message for every single one: `[...] status: The pool metadata is corrupted.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
 The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
 the '-f' flag.`

Comment: Try renaming your zfs cache file. It may also be worth trying upgrading to latest ZFS (0.8.3), and trying with that. The version that ships with Ubuntu is quite old.

Comment: Oh my, you're a life saver.  It was as simple as updating zfs.  Do you want to maybe put an answer suggesting to update and I'll accept that as the solution?  I built the latest 0.8.3 version from source and `zpool import -F zfs` just worked.

Comment: Updated the original answer.